# How can i use findBy in relational tables in spring data hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have attached a snapshot of my tables data .table name is `orderdetail`.

I want to get data on base of customers.  Like in my case data should be find on base of `PurchasedBy`.

```
@Entity
public class OrderDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="purchased_By")
    private User purchasedBy;
```

I am trying to use following query in `OrderDetailDao` repository

```
List<OrderDetail> findByPurchasedBy(User user);
```

but I am getting an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [purchasedBy] on this ManagedType [com.example.Domain.OrderDetail]
```

**Edit Summary >**
when i use `findAll()` and return json there `purchasedBy` section looks like this:

```
  "purchasedBy":{  
         "id":15,
         "email":"admin@gmail.com",
         "password":"$2a$10$jj41EbJZTOBfbKdJ6wAdx.rdQq8qU3OqoSzS5mvDVaiL33G1U4pPC",
         "name":"admin",
         "lastName":"admin",
         "active":1,
         "roleselected":null,
         "roles":[  
            {  
               "id":1,
               "role":"admin",
               "users":[  

               ],
               "new":false
            }
         ],
         "new":false
      }
   }
```

[image: OrderDetail Table image]

Comment: Does the `PurchasedBy` attribute in `OrderDetail` need to be `purchasedBy`?

Comment: I have checked with purchasedBy but not reolved issue .

Comment: i have tried purchasedBy , PurchasedBy, PurchasedById, no one worked . please suggest

Comment: Would be better to find by id instead of the user object. Oh, didn't see previous comment.

Comment: @CholNhial i have used too . List<OrderDetail> findBypurchasedBy(int id); but no effect

Comment: Can you post the relational mappings for both `OrderDetail` and `User`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think using a custom query might solve the issue:

`@Query("select od from OrderDetail od where od.PurchasedBy.id = ?1")
List<OrderDetail> findByPurchasedBy(Integer userId);`

Comment: caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found '?' near line 1

Comment: `@Query("select od from OrderDetail od where od.purchasedBy.id = ?1")`

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: purchasedBy of: com.example.Domain.OrderDetail [select od from com.example.Domain.OrderDetail od where od.purchasedBy.id = ?1]

Comment: let me try next then i will accept your answer . thanks

Comment: I'm glad I helped :).

Answer (score 2):

without using custom query jpa repository support this. check following code it working and i tested it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_details")
public class OrderDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "purchased_By")
private User purchasedBy;
}
```

Following is repository class:

```
public interface OrderDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderDetails, Integer> {
public List<OrderDetails> findByPurchasedBy(User user);
}
```

And service class method is like:

```
@Autowired
public OrderDetailsRepository orderDetailsRepository;

public List<OrderDetails> getUserOrders(Integer userId) {
    User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);
    return orderDetailsRepository.findByPurchasedBy(user);
}
```

using following dependency versions:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

There are many new features supported after jpa 1.4 check them.

Comment: Please try this also.